# why get simsimi by nodejs error

Tags: node.js

```
    var request = require('request');
    var cookie = null;

    var say = function(msg, cb) {
       request({
          'url': 'http://www.simsimi.com/func/req?msg=' + encodeURIComponent(msg) + '&lc=zh',
          'method': 'get',
          'headers': {
          'Cookie': cookie,
              'Referer': 'http://www.simsimi.com/talk.htm'
          }
       }, function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(response);
          console.log(body);
       });
    }

request({
   'url': 'http://www.simsimi.com/talk.htm',
   'method': 'get'
}, function(error, response, body) {
    cookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];
    cookie = (cookie + "").split(";").shift();
    console.log(cookie);
    say("hello");
}
```

I want get simsimi by nodejs 
but always return error { [Error: Parse Error] bytesParsed: 229, code: 'HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN' }
who can resolve;
thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Raw response headers via `curl --referer "http://www.simsimi.com/talk.htm" --cookie "JSESSIONID=A9E30C91FAEFFDD558ED295077F1CBFB" -i --raw http://www.simsimi.com/func/req\?msg\=hello\&lc\=zh`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 07 Jan 2013 22:52:07 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A6EF5185D0AFF3BAA3E25425B047687; Path=/; HttpOnly
text/html: utf-8
Content-Length: 57
Connection: keep-alive
```

You have **`text/html: utf-8`** instead of `Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`. Additionally you are not serving html, but json, which means your content type should be `application/json`.

Comment: but simsimi  is a http server online, we just send request and get response. so what can I do to receive the message with wrong content-type(content-type:html,but response json) ?

Comment: ask the maintainer to fix it. node seems to be a bit rigid in this regard. One solution would be to spawn a child process and use cURL to fetch the data.